# SQL query executing slowly (for some parameter values)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-profiler

I have a SQL Server 2005 database with several tables. One of the tables is used to store timestamps and message counters for several devices, and has the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Timestamps] (
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[MessageCounter] [bigint] NULL,
[TimeReceived] [bigint] NULL,
[DeviceTime] [bigint] NULL,
[DeviceId] [int] NULL
)
```

`Id` is the unique primary key (Guid.Comb), and I have indexes on both `DeviceId` and `MessageCounter` columns.

What I want to do is find the last inserted row (the row with the largest `MessageCounter`) for a certain device.

The thing that is strange is that a query for **device no. 4** (and all other devices except no.1) returns almost instantaneously:

```
select top 1 * 
   from "Timestamps"
   where DeviceId = 4
   order by MessageCounter desc
```

but the same query for **device no. 1** takes forever to complete:

```
select top 1 * 
   from "Timestamps"
   where DeviceId = 1 /* this is the only line changed */
   order by MessageCounter desc
```

The strangest thing is that device 1 has **much less rows** than device 4:

```
select count(*) from "Timestamps" where DeviceId = 4
(returns 1,839,210)

select count(*) from "Timestamps" where DeviceId = 1
(returns 323,276).
```

Does anyone have a clue what I could be doing wrong?

**[Edit]**

From the execution plans for both queries, it is clearly visible that Device 1 (lower diagram) creates a much larger number of rows in Index scan:

[Execution plans for device 4 (upper) and device 1 (lower) http://img295.imageshack.us/img295/5784/execplans.png](http://img295.imageshack.us/img295/5784/execplans.png)

The difference is when I hover the Index Scan nodes on execution plan diagrams:

```
Device 4 Actual Number of Rows: 1

Device 1 Actual Number of Rows: approx. 6,500,000
```

6,500,000 rows is a very strange number, since my `select count(*)` query returns around 300,000 rows for device 1!

Comment: Maybe refresh the index on DeviceID?

Comment: can you add the execution plan on both queries? than we know, what it changes. and afterwards we can guess, why it is that way... :-)

Comment: Ok, it looks like the statistics are out of sync - I assume the databases are set to auto update statsistics. Follow OMG Ponies' advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating an index on `(DeviceId, MessageCounter DESC)`.

Also, try this query:

```
select * 
   from "Timestamps"
   where DeviceId = 1
   and MessageCounter = (SELECT MAX(MessageCounter) FROM "Timestamps" WHERE DeviceID = 1)
```

Just guessing: The performance difference might be because `DeviceId = 1` is spread across more pages than `DeviceId = 4`. By sorting, I suspect you are dredging up all matching pages, even if you end up selecting only the top row.

Comment: Creating the index at first didn't seem to make it faster, but then it turned out I needed to change the order of my columns in the index (I didn't even know that order is important, sql noob, what more can I say). Making the DeviceId the first column in my composite index solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the statistics are up to date?  Use [UPDATE STATISTICS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx):

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Timestamps
```

How are you running the query?  If via a stored procedure, maybe you're having an issue with [parameter sniffing](http://www.sqlpointers.com/2006/11/parameter-sniffing-stored-procedures.html)?

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help either. My app is using LINQ to NHibernate, which produces shown queries for both devices. Right now I am simply using SQL Server Management Studio to enter both queries manually.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that this must be happening because if you order the records by `MessageCounter` descending there are 6,500,000 that it has to plough through before it finds the first one with `DeviceId=4` whereas for the other `DeviceId`'s there is a much better spread

I presume that the `DeviceId=4` predicate doesn't come into play until the Filter operator on the execution plan.

A composite index on `DeviceId, MessageCounter` would resolve this. But is the Device with `DeviceId=4` a legacy device for which new data is no longer being recorded? If so you may be able to get away with extracting the DeviceId=4 records into a table of their own and using a partitioned View so that queries on that device don't scan a load of unrelated records.

**Below Corrected**

Also What is the reason for choosing Guid.Comb as a clustered index?  I presume a clustered index on `DeviceId, MessageCounter` would have similar characteristics in terms of fragmentation and avoiding hot spots but be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

The execution plans diagramms are not very helpfull because they do not show which index are used.

The most helpfull informations comes from the following query

```
select DeviceId, max(MessageCounter) from "Timestamps" group by DeviceId
```

I assume the MessageCounter for Devices 2 to 4 are relative high numbers. The MessageCounter is a relative low number.

How does the SQL server executes the query in that case:

The server reads the MessageCounter index from high to low numbers. For every row the server make a nested seek into custered index to compare the device id.

For devices 2-4 this ends very soon, because the server finds a row in the MessageCounter Index for device 2-4. For device 1 the server needs more than 6 millions seek operations, before the server finds the first row for device 1.

It would be faster to read the deviceid index and seek into custered index. This should stops after 323k seeks. Even bad.

You should have an index that contains both the device ids and MessageCounter (as Marcelo Cantos pointed out).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your comment. You are right - as my db is growing, maximum MessageCounter for a specific Device which is relatively low compared to other Devices' MessageCounters is getting slower and slower to retrieve, even with the combined DeviceId+MessageCounter index. Do you think there is something else I could do? My last resort would be to separate each device into a different table, but that's some really crappy denormalization.

Comment: Ok, never mind, I am silly. I reordered the columns in my composite index, putting the DeviceId column to the top. My query now returns immediately.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was that this might be due to parameter sniffing - essentially SQL Server comes up with a plan for the first time a query is run, but that query was unrepresentative of the typical workload. See http://www.sqlshare.com/solve-parameter-sniffing-by-using-local-variables_531.aspx

The advice about statistics is good, but I suspect you'll need to have a look at the query plans for both these queries. You can do this in Query Analyser - it's about three buttons to the right of the Execute button. Try to see what is different between the plans for both queries...

Answer (score 0):

Are those queries sent to SQL Server **exactly** like you posted them

```
select top 1 * 
   from "Timestamps"
   where DeviceId = 4
   order by MessageCounter desc
```

or did NHibernate use parametrized queries? (`where deviceid = @deviceid` or something like that)??

That might explain it - SQL Server gets the parametrized query for DeviceId = 4, comes up with an execution plan that works for that parameter value, but then on the next execution, for DeviceId = 1, it stumbles and somehow the execution plan from the first query isn't optimal for that second case anymore.

Can you try to execute those two queries in the reversed order?? First with DeviceId=1 and then with DeviceId=4 - does that give you the same results??

Comment: At first I started checking NHibernate logs, but at the end I was simply using Management Studio to run queries manually. I tried running them in reverse, in several combinations (actually, for any device other than 1 query would execute instantaneously), but no change.