# Is it reasonable to divide data into different tables, based on a column value?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, database-design, normalization

If I have a large table with a column which has a rather limited range of values (e.g. < 100), is it reasonable to divide this table into several tables with names tied to that column value?

E.g. a table like with columns:

```
table "TimeStamps": [Id] [DeviceId] [MessageCounter] [SomeData]
```

where `[DeviceId]` is the "limited range" column would be separated into several different tables:

```
table "TimeStamps1": [Id] [MessageCounter] [SomeData]
table "TimeStamps2": [Id] [MessageCounter] [SomeData]
...
table "TimeStampsN": [Id] [MessageCounter] [SomeData]
```

The problem I am having with my original table is that finding a largest MessageCounter value for some DeviceId values takes really long time to execute (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180661/sql-query-executing-slowly-for-some-parameter-values) post).

If tables would be separated, finding a maximum column number should be an O(1) operation.

**[Edit]**

Just stumbled upon this, thought I would update it. The problem I originally brought me here was performance issues when querying the original database. However, after adding additional db indexes and scheduled index reorganizing jobs, I was able to get great performance with the normalized form. SSMS Database Engine Tuning Advisor tool was of great help for identifying bottlenecks and suggesting the missing indexes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you could do it as a last-ditch performance optimization, I would advise against it. Mainly because it makes it very difficult to accomodate new DeviceIDs.

At any rate, doing this should not be necessary. If there's an index for DeviceID, the DBMS should be able to filter on it very quickly. That's what a DBMS is for, after all...

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, it turned out that I ordered the columns in my composite index completely wrong. Moving the DeviceId column to top of my index returns results instantly.

Comment: @Groo: Yes, with indices the column order matters. I've run into the same problem in the past.

Comment: +1 This kind of solution (proposed by Groo) is kind of 'desperate measures'. Doing the tuning - specially index tuning - before going that path is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

I fear this approach would add a great deal to the complexity of any application which needed to access this data.  An alternate approach, which gains you whatever benefits you might get from putting each device in a separate table while still keeping all devices in the same table, would be to partition the table on DeviceID.  I suggest that you investigate table partitioning to see if it fits your needs.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

This is what a distributed database is for.  The servers share a table in the same database based on some column.  You tell the servers how to distribute the table based on ranges of column values.  Once this is set up you just query the table and aren't concerned on which server the data actually resides.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered Database partitioning? This is the baked in solution for the type of problem you've described. See: [Partitioned Tables and Indexes in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28SQL.90%29.aspx#sql2k5parti_topic6)